# Найти в реестре с++ Redistributable, отображаемый в "Программы и компоненты"

Tags: windows, реестр, inno-setup

Столкнулся с такой задачей. В Inno Setup необходимо получить список  с++ Redistributable, отображаемых в "Программы и компоненты". У каждой версии Redistributable есть свой адрес в реестре, который одинаковый на всех устройствах, однако, в реестре допустим 10 различных с++ Redistributable, а в "Программы и компоненты" только 3. Как получить только 3 этих варианта?

Comment: Скорее надо проверять `Product Code`. Вот [список](https://qtechbabble.wordpress.com/2017/08/08/microsoft-visual-c-redistributables-msi-product-codes/) для примера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как не нашел подобных тем изначально, нашел ответ самостоятельно, хочу поделиться им.

В моём случае, я искал с++ Redistributable в реестре, которые отображаются в "Программы и компоненты". Нужно инсталятором(или тем что вы используете) анализировать строку "DisplayName", например значение будет "Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable - x64 8.0.51011 False", **False** - означает что Redistributable не будет отображаться в списке "Программы и компоненты", если флаг отсутствует, соответственно - будет отображаться.